# ngx-wow not working angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, wow.js

I've never used this library before Im hoping someone who has can help me out,

Okay So I'm trying to use the [ngx-wow](https://github.com/tinesoft/ngx-wow) library but I cant get it to work.. so following the instructions

Ive run `yarn add wowjs`

I added it to `angular-cli.json`

```
"scripts": [
   "../node_modules/wowjs/dist/wow.js"
]
```

I also added `animate.css` as a global dependency the same way

```
"styles": [
   "../node_modules/animated.css/animate.css"
]
```

then I install `ngx-wow` following the instructions like so..

```
`yarn add ngx-wow`
```

then in my main module Ive imported the `ngwWowModule`

```
import { NgwWowModule } from 'ngx-wow';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [...],
    imports: [NgwWowModule.forRoot(), ...],
    bootstrap: [...]
})
```

then In the component I want to use wow.js

```
import { NgwWowService } from 'ngx-wow';

...


constructor (
   private wowService: NgwWowService
)

ngOnInit() {
   this.wowService.init();
}
```

and in my components html

```
<div class="wow fadeIn"></div>
```

but I cant get it to work in my console Im getting this error...

[image]

Im not sure what Im doing wrong any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see any major issues, Try adding the main.js without min.js in **angular-cli.json**

```
scripts": [
        "../node_modules/wowjs/dist/wow.min.js"
]
```

and initialize it under constructor

```
 constructor(private wowService: NgwWowService) {
    this.wowService.init();
  }
```

and sample **HTML**

```
 <h1 class="section-heading pt-4 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.6s">Why is it so great?</h1>
```